# Firefox will only print first page table

Tags: html, css, printing

I have an html page that is generated by the javascript library, canjs. The page generated is a set of tables with two columns, Field and Value. When printed, a css rule `page-break-after: always;` divides the tables into one table per page.

The issue is that firefox is only printing the first page table. The other pages are present, but none of the data actually shows. Instead, it just shows the headings (Field, Value) and one empty row.

Oddly, if I open the browser console and run `media emulate print` the correct styles are displayed, this issue only occurs in Print Preview, and when actually printed.

[image: Screenshot of media emulate print]

In print preview:

[image: Print preview screenshot]

Sample demo:
https://gistpreview.github.io/?eb94e2e59ae73047be5d263d94197349

I'm fairly certain the issue has to do with the page-break-after and the hidden-print classes, since if I remove that line, the print works, but I really need to put one table on each page when printed as a requirement. Is anyone familiar with this issue, or have any workarounds?

Comment: What environment? Print preview working here (Chrome latest stable on Windows10)

Comment: Firefox version 57 on windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: The issue does not occur in chrome. I've only seen it in firefox so far and it appears on other versions as well.

Comment: Sorry, I somehow missed the FF comment. Here's something: it's working for me on 55.0.3 (64 bit) Windows 10 but when I update to 57, it's not.

Comment: Okay, thanks for confirming. I've posted it on the mozilla forums, and they've created a bug.